# How to send confirmation email with Outlook from a SharePoint form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, form, outlook

I have created a InfoPath form with fields that gives visitors the option to register for a particular information session. I am trying to create a rule that sends each registrant and email confirmation with an attachment to add to their outlook calendar based on what session they chose. I do not have the ability to code anything within sharepoint designer or the other programs. Is it possible to do this with the out of the box features? If so, could you please walk me through it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is not an out-of-the-box feature that would send an email with a calendar attachment.  You would need to write code to add this functionality.